# XQuery to select element with multiple children containing same attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I need to perform a query on a XML document base to find records having multiple elements with very specific items. In SQL I would use GROUP BY, WHERE and HAVING.

I want to select `Lorem` if it has "expired" items. An item is expired if it's `lastDay` is in the past, or when the item has been replaced by a new item of the same `type`. This is the case when there is a second item with a more recent `firstDay` that is also in the past or equal to today.

Unfortunately I am restricted to a old version of XQuery and not all commands may be supported by the tool used: AG Tamino.

The query on `lastDay` is simple: `/Lorem[ipsum[dolor[item[@lastDay <= '2023-10-24']]]]`

The query on multiple items of same type where all `firstDay` are in the past or today is more difficult.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lorem>
   <ipsum>
      <dolor>
         <item id="1" type="ABC" firstDay="1980-01-01" />
         <item id="2" type="ABC" firstDay="1985-01-01" lastDay="1990-01-01" />
         <item id="3" type="ABC" firstDay="1995-01-01" />
         <item id="4" type="DEF" firstDay="2000-01-01" />
         <item id="5" type="DEF" firstDay="2023-10-25" lastDay="2050-01-01" />
         <item id="6" type="GHI" firstDay="2000-01-01" lastDay="2023-10-24" />
         <item id="7" type="GHI" firstDay="2050-01-01" />
      </dolor>
   </ipsum>
</Lorem>
```

I tried `count` and `following-sibling` solutions, but could not make it work. Some of my attempts:

```
/Lorem[ipsum[dolor[
  item[
    @firstDay <= '2023-11-25' and
      (
         @type = *[@firstDay <= '2023-11-25']/@type
      or
         @type = *[@firstDay <= '2023-11-25']/@type
     )
   ]
]]]
```

```
/Lorem[ipsum[dolor[
  item[
    @firstDay <= '2023-11-25' and
      (
         @type = preceding-sibling::[@firstDay <= '2023-11-25']/@type
      or
         @type = following-sibling::[@firstDay <= '2023-11-25']/@type
     )
   ]
]]]
```

I would want to find a match in (two with same type and firstDay before/equal today):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lorem>
   <ipsum>
      <dolor>
         <item id="1" type="ABC" firstDay="1980-01-01" />
         <item id="2" type="ABC" firstDay="1985-01-01" />
         <item id="4" type="DEF" firstDay="2000-01-01" />
      </dolor>
   </ipsum>
</Lorem>
```

but not in (none with same type where firstDay before/equal today)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lorem>
   <ipsum>
      <dolor>
         <item id="3" type="ABC" firstDay="1995-01-01" />
         <item id="4" type="DEF" firstDay="2000-01-01" />
         <item id="6" type="GHI" firstDay="2000-01-01" />
      </dolor>
   </ipsum>
</Lorem>
```

also not in (second with same type has firstDay in the future)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lorem>
   <ipsum>
      <dolor>
         <item id="3" type="ABC" firstDay="1995-01-01" />
         <item id="4" type="DEF" firstDay="2000-01-01" />
         <item id="6" type="DEF" firstDay="2050-01-01" />
      </dolor>
   </ipsum>
</Lorem>
```

**Edit:** I found the solution using XQuery:

```
for $target in input()/Lorem 
where 
  $target/ipsum/dolor/item/@lastDay <= xs:date('2023-11-24')
or
  for $type in distinct-values($target/ipsum/dolor/item/@type)
  where
    count( 
      for $item in $target/ipsum/dolor/item
        where $item/@firstDay <= xs:date('2023-11-25') 
        and   $item/@type = $type
      return $item
    ) > 1 
  return $type
return $target
```

Please let me know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You haven't said which version of XQuery you are using. There might be a solution here using "tumbling windows" (available in 3.0). You also haven't said whether all items with the same `@type` will be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me something like

```
some $item in $Lorem//item satisfies
  some $earlier-item 
    in $item/preceding-sibling::item[@type eq $item/@type]
    satisfies xs:date($earlier-item/@firstDay) lt current-date()
```